# IOS/Upgrade to Xcode 8.3 causing pngcrush caught libpng errors

Tags: ios, xcode, libpng

Because I inadvertently upgraded my iPhone SE OS to 10.3, Xcode required me to upgrade Xcode as well to run the app on the phone. I duly upgraded El Capitan to Sierra and Xcode to 8.3.2.  However, since doing that I still cannot build the app on the phone and now cannot build it in the simulator either.

I am getting multiple `pngcrush caught libpng error`s when the program gets to copying image followed by

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/copypng emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure
```

All of the answers on SO I have seen reference replacing the image files where it breaks with new ones.  However, in my case, the files where it crashes are different every time and appear random.  I would have to change every image.

Can anyone suggest how to get the app to build? Thank you.

Comment: were you able to solve this?